# JAXB - Unmarshaling repeating child element without a wrapper causes child to get overwritten for each instance

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm trying to unmarshal XML with the following structure:

```
<root>
  <student>
    <name>Sally</name>
    <test>
       <grade>A</grade>
    </test>
    <test>
       <grade>B</grade>
    </test>
  </student>
  <student>
    <name>Bob</name>
    <test>
       <grade>C</grade>
    </test>
  </student>
</root>
```

The repeating elements do not have wrapper elements.  I set up my POJOs as:

**ClassScores.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
public class ClassScores {
  private List<Student> students;

  @XmlElement(name = "Student")
  public List<Student> getStudents() {
    if (students == null)
        students = new ArrayList<Student>();
    return students;
  }
}
```

**Student.java**

```
public class Student {
  private String name;
  private List<Test> tests;

  @XmlElement(name="Name")
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  @XmlElement(name="Test")
  public List<Test> getTests() {
    if (tests == null)
      tests = new ArrayList<Test>();
    return tests;
  }
}
```

**Test.java**

```
public class Test {
  private String grade;

  @XmlElement(name="Grade")
  public String getGrade() {
    return grade;
  }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
public String unmarshal(String xml) {
  JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ClassScores.class);
  Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();  
  StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
  ClassScores c = (ClassScores) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
}
```

With this setup, I would expect each Student in the list to have it's own list of tests.  But instead, I end up with each student having only 1 test in the list (the last one in the list).

Comment: you don't need to initialize arrayList in getter.
Add these on class level variable initialization
private List<Test> tests = new ArrayList<Test>();
private List<Student> tests = new ArrayList<Student>();

Comment: in your case your list is being renewed when binder calls getter and only last element from the xml is mapping